# How to store server authentification in source code

Tags: nsstring, obfuscation, encryption

In my app I'm doing various request on server API. When I'm doing those requests, part of my requester class is:

```
NSString *authString = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"serverUsername:serverPass"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedString];
NSString *verifString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",authString];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[ms UTF8String] length:[ms length]];
[request setHTTPBody:myRequestData];
```

I'm not including all of source code, but then I have another strings, that I don't want to be visible in source code (fingerprints etc).

I was searching for code obfuscating, but to no success. Is there any way, to prevent my credential strings to be visible in x-code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to store it in a plist file.

```
- (NSString *)saveRecommendUserData {
  NSError *error;
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Userdata.plist"];
  NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

  if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
  {
      NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Userdata" ofType:@"plist"];
      [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error];
  }

  return path;
}
```

Comment: Hello Kalli, plist is certainly a nice tool, but I want to prevent person with my .pa or my sources, to just open and read all my passwords :)

Comment: i think this is no good idea at all, if you store all passwords in a file in your app. thats why you normaly store them on a server and use them with f.e. oauth. http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/oauth2-for-iphone-and-ipad-applications.html

Comment: and if you store them in your code, there is always a way to make all pass. visible if anyone else gets your code or .pa file

Comment: Well, I'm storing only necessary data in code.. For usernames and passwords I use keychain, but some data (like fingerprint, server credentials) are not user-specific. I looked at your link, thank you very much for that. We are dealing with various users on same device, so I'm not sure how to handle it with OAuth2. Upvoting for good link :)